# Passar Headers em uma rota no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth2

Boa Noite,
Estou trabalhando com o Laravel 5.3 em uma solução, por ser uma aplicação API, escolhi usar o Laravel Passport como autenticação. Eu estou com uma certa dificuldade em conseguir carregar o Token no cabeçalho da página, consigo fazer o login, retornar o token de acesso, o refresh token. Mas não consigo fazer iniciar as rotas com um cabeçalho personalizado com as informações arquivadas no LocalSession. Via postman consigo autenticar normalmente o acesso, mas via Laravel ainda não consegui adicionar as informações "Authorization" no header das rotas, tentei adicionar via header() na view porém não faz efeito pois o Middleware auth:api redireciona a página antes de ser aberta. Minha dúvida é, como consigo passar os tokens para o header da págin na rota antes do middleware entrar em ação? Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Você está usando o que no frontend? Vuejs? Posta sua arquitetura. Eu também estou usando laravel/passport na minha API e como estou utilizando vuejs estou fazendo assim:

> Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth.getJwtBearer();

Com essa configuração, em todas as requisições http ele seta o token no header

auth.getJwtBearer() é um serviço que eu criei que após o usuário for autenticado ele guarda o token e essa função me retorna 'Bearer token_id'